# MySQL - Сопоставить каждое значение из ячейки одного столбца со значениями в другом и заменить его значением из соседнего столбца

Tags: mysql

**Есть** таблица `contents`, которая содержит 13 столбцов и 1,5 млн строк.

[image: таблица contents]

Столбец `rel_gall` (text, utf8_general_ci) содержит в ячейках список значений с разделителем запятая.
Ячейка может содержать от нуля (ячейка может быть пустой) до тридцати значений с разделителем запятая. Значения между разделителем могут содержать буквы разного регистра и цифры.
(пример: cRbkmw,wiwvRDJ,ivhswa,iqexFT,hjJmkT,uiiwRnT,iklbJr,ibjTof,lvibeib,imiJoh).

Столбец `HEX` (varchar(250), utf8_general_ci) содержит в ячейках значение, которое встречается в ячейках столбца `rel_gall`. Столбец `HEX` не уникальный, строки повторяются. Из рандомного набора значений столбца `HEX` и состоит ячейка столбца `rel_gall`.

Столбец `HEX_new` (varchar(250), utf8_general_ci) содержит в ячейках новое значение HEX. На эти значения мы будем обновлять значения в столбце `rel_gall`. Столбец `HEX_new` не уникальный, строки повторяются.

**Нужно** сопоставить каждое значение из ячейки столбца `rel_gall` со значениями в ячейках столбца `HEX` (достаточно первого совпадения) и заменить значение из ячейки `rel_gall` на новое значение из соседнего столбца `HEX_new`.

Пример:

[image: таблица contents, пример]

Строка id 4. Значение в столбце `rel_gall` xRbhmw должно замениться на g3b1p5j7f3g1e1, hiiwRRJ -> z6k0d2f1c0t6k6, bbJmxT -> n0m3j7v6h1w8c5, iTohwbT -> q4o2p2o0o5l3p6, imibJo -> q7k4e3m1n1y3h1 и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ полностью обновлен после обсуждения.

Для начала лучше сделать копию таблицы `contents`, на всяк случай... если что-то пойдет не так. Потом сотрете.

Создаем временную таблицу.

```
CREATE TABLE `__temp` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tHEX` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `tHEX_new` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`tHEX`,`tHEX_new`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Вносим в нее данные (может занять время из-за `FIND_IN_SET()`)

```
INSERT INTO __temp (id, tHEX, tHEX_new)
SELECT c.id, c2.HEX, c2.HEX_new 
FROM contents c JOIN contents c2 ON FIND_IN_SET(c2.HEX, c.rel_gall)>0;
```

Обновляем источник

```
UPDATE contents c
JOIN (SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(tHEX_new) as hexes FROM __temp GROUP BY id) gr ON c.id=gr.id
SET c.rel_gall=gr.hexes;
```

Кстати, если так все сделать, то из `rel_gall` уйдут все строчки, которые не упомянуты в `contents.HEX`. Насколько я понял, в Вашем случае это как раз плюс. :)

Comment: Нет, Вы не так поняли. Наоборот, нужно заменить каждое значение в ячейке столбца `rel_gall` на соседнее (`HEX_new`) рядом с найденным в столбце `HEX`. Извиняюсь, если не совсем понятно объяснил...

Comment: @Den немного изменил ответ

Comment: Попробовал... чтобы ускорить тесты добавил в конец запроса условие `where c2.id < 5`. Работает только отчасти верно... берется самое первое по порядку значение из столбца `HEX`, ищется 
по колонке `rel_gall` и заменяется на `HEX_new`. Все. т.е. в колонке `rel_gall` из всего списка заменяется только одно значение. Если запустить еще раз, то возьмется следующее по списку за обработанным значение `HEX` и так же заменится по всему столбцу `rel_gall`. Получается, чтобы обработать весь столбец `rel_gall` нужно сделать столько запусков, сколько уникальных значений в столбце `HEX`.

Comment: Кстати, обработка четырех! столбцов занимает 276 сек. :) Добавлял FULLTEXT индекс на столбце rel_gall, запрос с EXPLAIN в possible_keys показывает NULL так же как и без индекса...

Comment: FULLTEXT индекс для этого не подходит - не тот тип индекса. В любом случае, тот факт, что при запуске меняется только одно значение (я об этом не подумал), аннулирует мой ответ. Не подходит. Думается мне, что решить Вашу задачу простыми средствами MySQL сложно. Можно еще функцию написать, но это может быть слишком много возни. Если Вам нужно пройтись по базе и все поменять лишь раз, и больше этого делать не придется, тогда надежней проще и быстрее будет какой-нить PHP код написать и запустить разок...

Comment: там тип строк text, поэтому FULLTEXT создавал. Можно поменять тип на, скажем VARCHAR(500), если это что то изменит... Да, поменять нужно раз, потом возможно раз в неск. месяцев будет добавление, так же пачкой, обработал её и все. В Excel я решал эту задачу так - разбивал строки на столбцы, выходило 30 столбцов, добавлял рядом пустой столбец и пробегался по каждому столбцу ВПР'ом. А в соседнем листе были два столбца HEX и HEX_new, в которых ВПР искал и брал соседнее значение. Тогда было до 1 млн строк, а сейчас их миллионы, поэтому перехожу на MySQL сразу, без обработки в Excel.

Comment: Продолжение... а после работы ВПР аналогом функции CONCAT собирал столбцы в строку... Это я к чему, может и тут так же сделать. Разбить каждую ячейку `rel_gall` на строки, чтобы в одной ячейке было одно значение, записать этот столбец в отдельную таблицу. Сделать UPDATE новой таблицы - сопоставить значения с колонкой `HEX` таблицы `contents`, заменить на значения `HEX_new`. А затем собрать обратно уже замененные значения, UPDATE'ом в таблицу `contents`... Только получится ли так сделать и как это все реализовать :)

Comment: Да, разбить `rel_gall` и сделать через отдельную таблицу - решение. Предварительно, вопрос - есть ли в `rel_gall` значения, которых нет в колонке `HEX`?

Comment: по поводу есть ли в `rel_gall` значения, которых нет в колонке `HEX`. Честно говоря, я даже не знаю... и не представляю как проверить. Значение в колонке `HEX` это идентификатор страницы, а в ячейке `rel_gall` идентификаторы страниц, которые выводились на этой странице в блоке Related. URL страниц собраны парсером, получается, если парсер пропустил какие то страницы, а на них ссылаются другие из блоков Related, то соответственно могут быть значения в `rel_gall`, которых не будет в колонке `HEX`.

Comment: @Den изменил ответ

Comment: Спасибо огромное за оперативные ответы и помощь! Создал вчера временную таблицу, запустил внесение в нее данных, еще жду завершения обработки... А насчет строчек, да, это даже хорошо :)

Comment: Запрос с внесением данных во временную таблицу (с FIND_IN_SET который) до сих пор еще обрабатывается, вторые сутки пошли :) Я пока создал копию БД в миниатюре с тысячей строк, проверил работу решения на ней. Все работает. Точность точно не проверить, т.к. не все значения находятся из-за сильно обрезанной БД. А так логика работает, все хорошо. Жаль, что на большой БД ждать надо очень долго... Отмечу текущий ответ решением.

Comment: Я кстати, решил поменять структуру хранения и нормализовать данные. Уйти от CSV в сторону дополнительной связующей таблицы. Сейчас пробую это все реализовать...

Comment: Раз был помочь.
Да, дополнительная связующая таблица - правильное решение при таких объемах. Обработка текстовых данных - дико долгой процесс :) Удачи

Comment: Спасибо огромное за Вашу помощь! Я ценю это. Обработка... да уж, долгий :))